# Android addView

Tags: android, view

I have problems to replace a view.

Here is my View Container:

```
Container View
  --> newMethod 0
      --> savedMethod 0
      --> savedMethod 1
          [...]
  --> newMethod 1
      --> savedMethod 0
      [...]
```

Currently, I have two newNethod Views and some saveMethod views.

I want to change a savedMethod view, which are clicked. Here is the code

```
savedMethod.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       mSelectedViewIndex = ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).indexOfChild(v);
       mSelectedView = v;
       mSelectedViewClicked = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.component_saved_method_container_01_selected,null);

       ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).removeView(v);

       ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).addView(mSelectedViewClicked, mSelectedViewIndex);
       // ((ViewGroup) saveMethod.getParent()).addView(mSelectedViewClicked, mSelectedViewIndex);
  [...]
```

I have detected, that my addView line produce a Nullpointer Exception:

```
03-21 14:36:33.608: E/AndroidRuntime(13192): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 14:36:33.608: E/AndroidRuntime(13192):    at com.xxxx.xxxx.view.NativeProfileFragment$4.onClick(NativeProfileFragment.java:326)
03-21 14:36:33.608: E/AndroidRuntime(13192):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
03-21 14:36:33.608: E/AndroidRuntime(13192):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
[...]
```

If I change this line to following:

```
((ViewGroup) saveMethod.getParent()).addView(mSelectedViewClicked, mSelectedViewIndex);
```

Then the changes works. But only for the last added newMethod (1) saveMethods. If I click now a saveMethod from newMethod (0), then my code get the right index an replace a savedMethod from newMethod (1) on the index. It seems logicaly because, I use saveMethod.getParent(). But how I can get work this with all newMethods?

Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem.

I saved the ViewParent **v.parent()** in a variable and use this.

Here is the final code:

```
savedMethod.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       mSelectedViewIndex = ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).indexOfChild(v);
       mSelectedView = v;
       mSelectedViewParent = v.getParent();
       mSelectedViewClicked = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.component_saved_method_container_01_selected,null);

       ((ViewGroup) mSelectedViewParent).removeView(v);
       ((ViewGroup) mSelectedViewParent).addView(mSelectedViewClicked, mSelectedViewIndex);
       // ((ViewGroup) saveMethod.getParent()).addView(mSelectedViewClicked, mSelectedViewIndex);
  [...]
```

Now it works. But I can't understand why this not working without storing the ViewParent in a variable.